# Using 'adb backup' to backup application programmatically

Tags: java, android, sqlite, adb

Currently, I'm performing backups of my application using the `adb backup` command with my device connect to my pc via a micro usb cable. The command looks like as follows:

```
adb backup -f Backups/app.ab -noapk com.me.app
```

Which outputs and android backup (ab) file called app.ab in my Backups folder.

I'm wondering if it's possible to backup an app to the SD Card programmatically? I just need to backup the app and it's databases periodically.

Any links/docs on this issue would be helpful.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run `ADB` commands (like `backup`) from your application, but you can run `SHELL` commands (the `LINUX` commands that run from inside the `SHELL`), like this -

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("my_command");
```

If you know your target and destination folders, you can use `cp` command to copy files. 
If you want to read the results of your commands, use

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

Make sure your app has the proper permissions for writing to the `SD`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the source code for adb (source: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/blob/master/adb/daemon/services.cpp).

I figure out that the

**/system/bin/bu backup packagename**

and

**/system/bin/bu restore < filename.ab**

is the shell command that can be run to backup and restore.

Unfortunately this didn't worked for my device without root access

Only the code below works for rooted devices:

```
try {
    Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

    outputStream.writeBytes("/system/bin/bu backup all\n");
    outputStream.flush();

    outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
    outputStream.flush();
    su.waitFor();
} catch(Exception e) {}
```